# CoreData doesn't save data to database

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

I am programming an iOS app using Swift, following a tutorial on Youtube. The app will have the same function as a to-do-list-app, but another use. However, when I expect the data to be saved (and printed in the debugger) nothing happens. Have I done something wrong?

```
 @IBAction func saveTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    println("SaveTapped")

    // Reference to our app delegate

    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate

    // Reference moc

    let contxt: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
    let en = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Tankningslista", inManagedObjectContext: contxt)

    // Create instance of our data model and initialize

    var nyTankning = Model(entity: en!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: contxt)

    // Map our properties

    nyTankning.liter = (textFieldLiter.text as NSString).floatValue
    nyTankning.kronor = (textFieldKronor.text as NSString).floatValue
    nyTankning.literpris = (textFieldLiterpris.text as NSString).floatValue
    //nyTankning.datum = datePickerDatum.date

    // Save our context

    contxt.save(nil)

    println(nyTankning) //HERE I ESPECT THE DATA TO BE PRINTED IN THE DEBUG WINDOW

    // navigate back to root vc
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)


}
```

Comment: I suggest you pass an error variable to `context.save` and examine it afterward to determine if the save was successful

Comment: Willfully ignoring the return value of `save` and not passing in an `NSError` in case of an error is asking for this kind of silent failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fetch the data first in order to display. Now you only save it. See my additions in your code after saving the data.

@IBAction func saveTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    println("SaveTapped")

```
// Reference to our app delegate

let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate

// Reference moc

let contxt: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
let en = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Tankningslista",inIntoManagedObjectContext: contxt)

// Create instance of our data model and initialize
// Use your NSManagedModel to initialize not only the Model Keyword!
var nyTankning = Tankningslista(entity: en!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: contxt)

// Map our properties

nyTankning.liter = (textFieldLiter.text as NSString).floatValue
nyTankning.kronor = (textFieldKronor.text as NSString).floatValue
nyTankning.literpris = (textFieldLiterpris.text as NSString).floatValue
//nyTankning.datum = datePickerDatum.date

// Save our context

 if contxt.save(nil) {

// Fetch the Data from Core Data first....

let fetchRequest = NSfetchRequest(entityName: "Tankningslista")
var error:NSError?

var result = contxt.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as [Tankningslista]

    for res in result {
     // Now you can display the data
        println(res.liter)
        ......
        ......
     }

// End of the fetching

} else {

println(error)    

}

//println(nyTankning) //HERE I ESPECT THE DATA TO BE PRINTED IN THE DEBUG WINDOW

// navigate back to root vc
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

I hope that solution will solve your problem.

Comment: "Use of undeclared type 'Tankningslista'" on the var result - line?

Comment: Normally that should work as I used your Managed Object "Tankningslista"- you should maybe check if the object is saved. - I revised my code take a look now....

Comment: It is printed, and I can retrieve the LATEST saved data in my UITableViewController. Every time I save, a new row is added, but with the data from the latest save.

Comment: Yes, your solution fixed it. I´ll give you more info

Answer (score 0):

Puuh, there is a lot to improve, I really suggest you take a "real" iOS/ swift course on a platform like Udemy/ Bitfountain or Udacity. First, you need to fetch the ManagedObject somewhere either in a function (then store the results in an array) or with NSFetchedResultController (which is mostly used for CoreData with TableViews) then I am not sure what you have in your numberOfRowsInSection function, here you should also have the correct return values. As I said, to fix that here is really too much...

Comment: wasn't that what we did to check if the data was saved? Can I do the same thing in the UITABLEVIEWCONTROLLER and then save it in an array?

Comment: That is a bit more complex, your TableView needs to know how many rows to draw and this depends on the entries in your CoreData furthermore you need to get the values somewhere in an array and you can't do that in the "cellForRowAtIndexPath" function. So you need either an additional function or you do it with the NSFetchedResultController.... But as I said, you should really take your time for a course, it is absolutely worth it, there are some which are for free as well...